# I need to know what diode to use to protect a 9V battery when connected directly to a 12V battery ( +to+ and - to -)

Tags: diodes

When connecting a 9V battery to a 12 volt battery what diode do I need to protect the 9V battery?

Comment: What do you expect this will *do*?

Comment: Why do you want to connect a 9V battery to a 12V battery? It is not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: It's an assist for an engine starter system. I simple need to know which diode will protect a 9v battery from overvolt from a 12 volt battery. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *what diode do I need to protect the 9V battery?*

This circuit will protect the 9 volt battery from the 12 volt battery: -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmbV0K.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the 12 volt battery is fresh and energized, the 9 volt battery will not be called into action. However, should the 12 volt battery become depleted, the 9 volt battery will take over at a load voltage of about 8.5 volts until it becomes depleted. Not a great circuit but possibly has some benefit.